# NEMA 17 connector part number

Tags: connector, stepper-motor

I want to route a cable for the NEMA 17 (2 coils) like [this one](https://www.joy-it.net/files/files/Produkte/NEMA17-04/Datasheet%20NEMA17-04.pdf). As I understand it, the wire connectors are [these](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Rectangular-Connectors-Housings_JST-Sales-America-PHR-6_C157952.html) with [these pins](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Line-Pressing-Terminals_JST-Sales-America-SPH-002T-P0-5L_C265456.html). Wire gauge is 26 AWG.

Can you please help me validate that I chose the right ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the mating plug housing is indeed the JST PHR-6. But the contact depends on the wire size you plan to use. The contact you picked is for 24-28 AWG wire.

Comment: Thank you. I an using a 26AWG cable so this will work.